# phpMyAdmin get error 404 for php 5.5.8

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I just upgraded my PHP version from 5.3 to 5.5.8

When i was trying to connect back to phpMyAdmin i got the message:

> Not Found

The requested URL `/phpmyadmin/` was not found on this server.

> Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.168.59 Port 80

What can be the problem?

I restarted to apache2 server and updated all the apps with `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstall phpmyadmin and it was the simple way to do so.

Because, it maybe PHP5.5.X removed PHP/APACHE virtual host. If you know how to put it back the virtual host, you may try it. else try reinstall it

Comment: i re-install it but still the same

Comment: for the server? Ubuntu linux server

Comment: i am running the ubuntu server on a virtual box. all my webpage are being loaded fine, the problem is only with phpmyadmin

Comment: ok we try debug it.

go to "/etc/apache2/conf.d" do you have see "phpmyadmin.conf" configuration file?

Comment: After that, open "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf". check it got include all the conf.d file or not. it will look like "include conf.d/"

Comment: in "/etc/apache2/conf.d" i have "phpmyadmin.conf@".  in "/etc/apache2/apache2.conf" i don't find "include conf.d/".

Comment: try add "include conf.d/" then restart your apache2

Comment: Where should i add it in the file?

Comment: and why it worked before the upgrade and now it doesn't?

Comment: OK, i got it working again by adding "include conf.d/" in the "include module configuration"